# Proving multiplication of sums

Tags: summation, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Can someone please explain to me\prove why:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k)\sum_{j=1}^{n}g(j) = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n f(k) g(j)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that for any $1\leq k\leq n$, 
$$\sum_{j=1}^n f(k)g(j)=f(k)g(1)+\dots +f(k)g(n)=f(k)\left(g(1)+\dots+g(n)\right)=f(k)\sum_{j=1}^n g(j).$$

Answer (score 1):

It is the distributive property.  You have $n^2$ terms on the right and the product of two $n$ term sums on the left.  If you look closely and distribute the product on the left you get all the terms on the right.  Try it with $(1+2+3)(4+5+6)=1\cdot 4 + 1 \cdot 5+\ldots 3 \cdot 6$ and see.